# Flagging directly or commenting first?

Tags: support, flags

Should I directly flag questions, or should I give the author a comment first and give him time to fix the problem?

The use case here is a question were the author forgot to ask his question or didn't include the necessary information, so the question is unclear.

Comment: Always flag first. The person had infinite time to add the appropriate information to their question *before* asking it. It isn't your job to wait around even longer.

Comment: I comment when I see room for improvement, and flag when I do not. Note that 'see' means me being able to give feedback on a question, if not: VLQ flag and have someone that does take a look at it.

Comment: To be honest @CodyGray I find the Ask question window horribly designed and had my good share of bad questions. Once a certain length is reached it's easy to not make a coherent question, because you can't see the whole question while typing. Or have to scroll up and down, which honestly isn't practical when you do a lot of corrections.

Comment: Then write it in a separate editor. If you have trouble scrolling up and down in an editor, I'm not sure how you manage to successfully write code. But anyway, that sort of misses the point. A flag doesn't mean the person should be banned permanently because they made a mistake. It means that the question has a problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Code is made up of lines (vs sentences) and well defined cross references and you have a lot of features that let you jump coherently to what you are referencing (jump to method/jump to declaration) and then let you jump back conveniently. I have yet to see a text editor for normal language with such features. But I'm not a friend of forcing yourself to use command lines like bash for everything if I can get the functionality from a gui. Also like you mentioned, the window isn't a real editor and has a lot of problems, especially for beginners. (You need to learn how to paste code first, hehe)

Comment: @StephenLeppik How so?  It's literally asking exactly the same thing.  The question is unclear, and he wants to know if he should close it as unclear or wait.  That's exactly what the question answers.

Comment: @Servy That question is about the review task of closing the question, this question is about  flagging and commenting.  The two can have very different outcomes.  If a question is just flagged, there is still time that the asker can re-work the question to improve it, if it is closed, it is dead.

Comment: While I agree the questions aren't the same, I think the answer answers both, as long as it's correct and still the current stance of the community.

Comment: @Barker Flagging for closure and voting for closure aren't meaningfully different in this context.  You should flag to close in exactly the same situations that you should vote to close, the flag is simply what you do if you don't have 3k rep.

Comment: @Barker "if it is closed, it is dead"  No, it's not.  If it is fixed, it can be reopened.  Flagging a question for closure is doing literally nothing other than informing people with the privilege to vote to close that the question warrants their attention for possible close votes.  It does nothing to help the question get re-worked or improved.  It's actually closing it that does that.

Comment: I agree thought that closed stuff is dead. I haven't seen something reopened unless it was really really good and still had attention. Do we have any reopen queues ? I think the bar for reopening is much higher than for not getting closed in the first place.

Comment: @Servy Even if you disagree about the use of flagging vs close vote, there is a second aspect of this question that is different from that one, which is the commenting aspect.  In a comment, you can directly address the asker saying things like "please include data in your question using instructions found at [link]" where as the other question is just about the amount of time that should pass.  In that case, the asker may have no information on the problem with their question than the "Too vague" or "Unclear" generic text box.

Comment: Yes, there's a re-open queue: http://stackoverflow.com/review You get access to it at 3K: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: @Barker But that's not different.  The duplicate discusses the exact same situation.  (Not that that's actually relevant in any way anyway, the answer is still exactly the same.)

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful It is indeed fairly uncommon for closed questions to get reopened, but that's because question authors very rarely actually take the time to improve their quesitons when there are problems with them pointed out.  When they actually do address the problems that caused the question to be closed there's a very good track record of it getting reopened.